# Is my triangle right?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, geometry

Given `a, b, c` the length of the three sides of a triangle, say if the triangle is **right-angled** (i.e. has one angle equal to 90 degrees) or not.

### Input

Three **positive** integer values **in any order**

### Output

Either a specific true output (`true`, `1`, `yes`, ...) or a specific false output (`false`, `0`, `no`, ...)

### Example

```
5, 3, 4        --> yes
3, 5, 4        --> yes
12, 37, 35     --> yes
21, 38, 50     --> no
210, 308, 250  --> no
```

### Rules

- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- In your submission, please state the true and the false values.
- No need to handle **negative** values or **invalid edge** triple
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Must we handle negative values or invalid edge triple?

Comment: @user202729 No ;)

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35053/three-pointer-but-what-kind).  I'll leave it up to the rest of the community to decide if its a dup.

Comment: I think that using coordinates instead of lengths changes the challenge significantly

Comment: There is no triangle with lengths `21, 38, 5`, because [21 + 5 < 38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).  Is this an intentional pathological case that we have to handle?

Comment: @Kevin no you have not to handle this case. User202729 has already asked this question :)

Answer (score 38):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
²µSHe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpkNbgz1S////b6xjomMKAA)

Technical note: Bytes are counted in Jelly codepage.

Explanation:

```
²µSHe  Main link.
²      Square each number.
 µ     With the new list,
  S    calculate its sum,
   H   and halve it.
    e  Check if the result exists in the new list (squared input)
```

The problem is equivalent to being given three numbers `a, b, c`, and asking if there is a permutation such that `a² + b² = c²`. This is equivalent to whether `(a² + b² + c²) ÷ 2` is one of `a², b² or c²`, so the program just checks that.

Comment: well... I jelly.

Comment: Just a technical note: symbols `²` and `µ` cost two bytes each in UTF-8, so your code has actually 7 bytes, not 5

Comment: @Charlie Answer edited for clarification.

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
a,b,c=sorted(input())
1/(a*a+b*b-c*c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnSSfZtji/qCQ1RSMzr6C0RENTk8tQXyNRK1E7SStJN1krWfP//2hDIx0FY3MgNo0FAA)

-2 thanks to [FlipTack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60919/fliptack).
-1 thanks to [Craig Gidney](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74349/craig-gidney).

Outputs via exit code (`0` = false, `1` = true).

Comment: Bah. Came up with the exact same answer. You could modify the test suite to allow for any number of test cases: [see here](https://tio.run/##JczBCsMgDAbgu08hntR5UDfZKPgkZQe1gQpDpXV0e3qXbYeQ/0tC2ruvtdiR6gKeMTaCiir5vW4dFp5Le3YuBGlbLp0GGU5RRu@TTAOPybHmB1AzwQsS/74QY3aKnhW93MmMzf2TsTi8YjmENRhuuNM/aJRGWvQH)

Comment: @mbomb007 `exec(code)` hmmm, why `exec (code)` instead of `exec code`? :D ;-p

Comment: Haha, how does this answer have double the upvotes of xnor's shorter one? Maybe people just like the sweet simpleness of it

Comment: @FlipTack ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (also xnor's isn't in Python 2)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Because the boilerplate isn't the part that is to be golfed. I made it so it'd work in either Python 2 or 3.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'd say that's not necessary, since this won't work in Python 3 anyways.

Comment: You could use `1/(a*a+b*b!=c*c)` to output by exit code.

Comment: Use `-` instead of `!=` to save a byte.

Answer (score 17):

## Java 8, 44 bytes

```java
(a,b,c)->(a*=a)+(b*=b)==(c*=c)|a+c==b|b+c==a
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hc5BasMwEAXQfU7xl5KjmDitaSGoN2g2WZYuRhO1KHUkEyuB0vjs7rjOthg0DGIen3@kK61S6@Px8DVwQ12HVwrxZwGEmP35g9hjN34Bl1LjKYKVnEBmFHDTYr0V08vI6zLlwNghwmJQZJxhvXpRVFjSS@UK67S1igvL@kZLttbd3Lho2E4J7cU1knAPuqZwwElqqX0@h/j59g7SU6f9d5f9qUyXXLZyyk1UsWRVGzwYPOq/Vv8qIfW8qjYS9iRTz8BNJehZMmfdWuBaZHWn/aIffgE)

```java
(a,b,c)->                // Method with three integer parameters and boolean return-type
  (a*=a)+(b*=b)==(c*=c)  //  Return if `a*a + b*b == c*c`
  |a+c==b                //  or `a*a + c*c == b*b`
  |b+c==a                //  or `b*b + c*c == a*a`
                         // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Comment: Does it work without the parenthesis on the `(c*=c)`? The `*=` might have precidence over the `==` and you can save two bytes.

Comment: @corsiKa I'm afraid it's the other way around. `==` has precedence over `*=`. `=`, `+=`, `*=`, and similar assignments actually have [the lowest precedence in Java operators](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Comment: Can't find anything shorter... I tried to get the variables swapped to have the max value assigned to `a` (for instance), without any success. Well, I could do it, but around 65 characters...

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda*l:sum(x*x/2for x in l)**.5in l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSvHqrg0V6NCq0LfKC2/SKFCITNPIUdTS0vPFMT4X1CUmVeikaZhqqNgrKNgoqnJBRMBck1RRQyNgIrMgdgUSdDIEChgAVSLImYAFDQAihoChf8DAA)

Might run into float precision issues with large inputs.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

*Saved 1 byte and fixed a bug thanks to @Neil*

Takes input as an array of 3 integers. Returns `true` for right-angled and `false` otherwise.

```js
a=>a.some(n=>Math.hypot(...a,...a)==n*2)
```

```js
let f =

a=>a.some(n=>Math.hypot(...a,...a)==n*2)

console.log(f([5, 3, 4     ])) //  --> yes
console.log(f([3, 5, 4     ])) //  --> yes
console.log(f([12, 37, 35  ])) //  --> yes
console.log(f([21, 38, 5   ])) //  --> no
console.log(f([210, 308, 15])) //  --> no
```

---

## Original version, 44 bytes

Takes input as 3 integers. Returns `1` for right-angled and `0` otherwise.

```js
(a,b,c)=>(a*=a)+(b*=b)==(c*=c)|a+c==b|b+c==a
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

(a,b,c)=>(a*=a)+(b*=b)==(c*=c)|a+c==b|b+c==a

console.log(f(5, 3, 4     )) //  --> yes
console.log(f(3, 5, 4     )) //  --> yes
console.log(f(12, 37, 35  )) //  --> yes
console.log(f(21, 38, 5   )) //  --> no
console.log(f(210, 308, 15)) //  --> no
```

Comment: Looks like we came up with the exact same answer (except for the `=>` and `->` difference between JavaScript and Java 8). ;) So obvious +1 from me.

Comment: `>>1` is unsafe, this returns true for `[1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: How about `Math.hypot(...a,...a)==n*2`?

Comment: @Neil Very nice fix :)

Comment: @Neil I was trying to do `Math.hypot(...a)**2==2*n*n` and couldn't understand why it didn't work :(

Comment: @JollyJoker Floating-point errors perhaps?

Comment: @Neil Yes, I logged `Math.hypot(...a)**2-2*n*n` and get errors of order 10^-15. `hypot(...a,...a)` seems to get around it, likely because the (desired) result is always an integer.

Comment: @JollyJoker Indeed, it's always an integer for Pythagorean triples, which is how I came up with the idea!

Comment: @Neil There should be a `~=` operator for "rougly equal" ;)

Comment: ```a=>Math.hypot(...a,...a)==a.sort()[2]*2```

Comment: @l4m2 This would fail for instance for `[10,6,8]`, because `sort()` uses lexicographical order by default.

Comment: Checked. And thus the [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146101/76323) using sort are also invalid

Comment: @l4m2 Oh, I didn't notice that one. But it would fail indeed on such test cases.

Comment: Builtin function way and [recursive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151773/76323) way exactly both 40c

Comment: `f=a=>a.some(n=>Math.hypot(...a,n,n)==n*2)` late improvement

Answer (score 8):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 57 bytes

I haven't seen any in this language yet and it seemed appropriate to try and do one.  It took a bit ... as I had to get my head around it first and I believe this could be golfed some more.

```
,$\:$:*/%*$"`=P:pp.0"*>/>-`:S!>/U+<U"g+..>p`S:U/U"p`!g<>/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0clxkrFSktfVUtFKcE2wKqgQM9ASctO3043wSpY0U4/VNsmVCldW0/PriAh2CpUP1SpIEEx3cZO//9/EwVTBWMA)

This expands to the following triangle.

```
          ,
         $ \
        : $ :
       * / % *
      $ " ` = P
     : p p . 0 "
    * > / > - ` :
   S ! > / U + < U
  " g + . . > p ` S
 : U / U " p ` ! g <
> /
```

The path is quite convoluted, but I'll try and explain what I have done.  I will skip the directional pointers.  Most of the code is stack manipulation.

- `$:*` Square the first input.
- `$:*` Square the second input.
- `S":Ug!` Test if the second value is greater than the first.

  - ***true*** `p"` Swap with the first.
  - ***false*** `p` Do Nothing.
- `$:*` Square the third input.
- `P":USg!` Test if the third value is greater than the greatest of the previous.

  - ***true*** `p+U-` sum the current stack and take away stored third value
  - ***false*** `p"U+-` sum the least and stored third and subtract from greatest
- `0=%` test equality to zero and output result.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 <s>26</s> <s>30</s> bytes

```r
cat(sum(a<-scan()^2)/max(a)==2)
```

I don't like this one as much, but it is shorter.  Sums the squares and divides by the largest square.  Truthy if 2.

***Previous Version (modified with cat and with @Guiseppe's tip)***

```r
cat(!sort(scan())^2%*%c(1,1,-1))
```

Do a sum of the sorted input with the last item negated and return the `!` not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0VyPRRrc4OTFPQzPOSFM/N7FCI1HT1tbov6mCsYLJfwA)

Comment: For your previous version, `!sort(scan())^2%*%c(1,1,-1)` is 27 bytes. but I think you still need a `cat`.

Comment: Cheers @Guiseppe, forgot about the cat.  The rules around REPL annoy me, but they are what they are.

Comment: @Giuseppe Also nice twist with the matrix multiplication.  I would never have come up with that.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell (<strike>33</strike> <strike>32</strike> 31 bytes)

```
(\x->(sum x)/2`elem`x).map(^2)
```

Original version:

```
(\x->2*maximum x==sum x).map(^2)
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list in the form [a,b,c]. Outputs True or False.

First version checked if the sum of the squares was twice the square of the maximum.

Second, slightly better version checks if half the sum of squares is an element in the list of squares.

Edit: Accidentally counted a newline, thanks H.PWiz

Comment: Welcome to the site! This answer is only 32 bytes, maybe you counted an extra newline?

Comment: You can use the function Monad to save some more bytes [here](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyM1JzXX1sZGQ99IU6@4NFdTLzexQCPOSPN/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkK0iY6xjmns/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Comment: also, the parentheses around `sum` can be thrown away. nice solution!

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
{(*²+*²==*²)(|.sort)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkPr0CZtILa1BRKaGjV6xflFJZq1/60VihMrFZRU4q0UqtMUVOJrlRTS8osUbEwVjBVM7HQUbIwVTCEMQyMFY3MFY1MQ28hQwdhCAco0UDA2sFAwNLWz/g8A)

`*²+*²==*²` is an anonymous function that returns true if the sum of the squares of its first two arguments is equal to the square of its third argument.  We pass the sorted input list to this function, flattening it into the argument list with `|`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 68 bytes

```
({({({})({}[()])}{}<>)<>})<>({<(({}){}<>[({})])>(){[()](<{}>)}{}<>})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6MaBGs1gThaQzNWs7a61sZO08auFog1qm00QHIgoWgQI1bTTkOzGqROw6a61g6iuFbz/38jQwUjSwUjAwA)

Uses the observation in user202729's answer.

```
 {                      }      for each input number
   {({})({}[()])}{}            compute the square
  (                <>)<>       push onto second stack
(                        )     push sum of squares onto first stack
                          <>   move to second stack

 {                                    }    for each square
   (({}){}<>[({})])                        compute 2 * this square - sum of squares
  <                >(){[()](<{}>)}{}<>     evaluate loop iteration as 1 iff equal
(                                      )   push 1 if any squares matched, 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:(a*a+b*b+c*c)/2in(a*a,b*b,c*c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcqxDkAwFIXh3VN0pG5CS0Mk3sRyWxESSsTi6esYBMMZ/i9nO49x9ToMbRdmXmzPgsmSa2KWnFppUyddkunJ30AAuiFs@@QPMcSGREGiTKIHUOYHSuNSYeY1rdA1nl/KYTlQQcMF)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>79</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 62 bytes

```python
lambda*l:any(A*A+B*B==C*C for A,B,C in zip(l,l[1:]+l,l[2:]+l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSvHKjGvUsNRy1HbScvJ1tZZy1khLb9IwVHHScdZITNPoSqzQCNHJyfa0CpWG0QbgWhNzf8FRZl5JQppGqY6CsY6CiaaXDABIM8URcDQCKjEHIhNEWJGhkC@BVAlspABUMwAKGgIFP0PAA)

Comment: The challenge was updated to limit inputs to integers.

Comment: 77 bytes https://tio.run/##hY/BCoMwDIbvPkVgF@ti0dayMXCgPsbYQZ0yL1U6d/Dpu9RtMARdDn8o3/8nzTCN914La29NC61fYoU1O5lmfBoNpZ78LAjEPidJ04K07Q1kmGMBnb587Ei9xoo6vbBkV2YH0@mR5kmEBEGxHbwrDM8wNQ/vhyuyrHIKy618MuflKlfz/k0u/@xXPCITj2bPksdcOHhw4n655ILHDh2/Nziue8@@AA

Comment: `A*A` is shorter...

Comment: 68 bytes https://tio.run/##VcqxCsIwGATg3af4xyT@QxMNipAhyWOoQ1IJFjQtpUufPh6CqMNx3MdN63Ifq2nFXdojPfMtUeLM/SnVVXjlt0EF56KKVMaZPAeONNSzeJ8ko3vOaCxO8irbNA91oSIs045pLzcfwLJ/oA0uB8R@zWjsI56/1ME6oIa2Fw

Comment: @mdahmoune [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcrBCgIhGATge0/xH9X@YLWkCDqoj1EddENaMHdZ9tLT2xBEdRiG@ZjpudzHalo@XVqJj3SLFDlxf4ylCKfc2iu/CSpQHmdy7DnQUM/i/ZGM7jmhsTjKq2zTPNSFsrBMW6adXH0Ay/6BNrjsEfs1o7EPeP5SB@uAGtpe); flipping the truth value's meanings and using `-` instead of `==`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech you right :-)

Comment: 43 bytes: `lambda a,b,c:(a*a+b*b+c*c)/2in(a*a,b*b,c*c)`.

Comment: 41 bytes: `lambda*x:sum(y*y for y in x)/2==max(x)**2`

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
n(a,b,c){return(a*=a)+(b*=b)-(c*=c)&a+c-b&b+c-a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzBCsIwDIbvfYoycTRbJ@u0KMz5JF7adGpBq8zuNPbsNXh2BhL4830JVlfEtPIB76Pr@fEdnX9ubieWgjDSSoRp6OM4UCo6A6WwRWehElh0CLkpsbK5pWnaOfkQ@cP4IIBNjFO9BlpdRLZ255DJILTkW8l3AO1PTEz/waqh8z21XjIaRfRAX5aFmoyaFPV12Jw@)

Improves on [Kevin Cruijssens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146064) technique

Returns 0 for a valid triangle, and a non-zero value otherwise

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Does it always work if you're using bitwise operations?

Answer (score 4):

## C,  <s>68</s>  54 bytes

Using [user202729's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146061/61405).

```c
f(a,b,c){return!((a*=a)+(b*=b)-(c*=c)&&a-b+c&&a-b-c);}
```

*Thanks to @Christoph for golfing 14 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCoMwDIbvPkUmTBJtwerKBuKb7NJmc3iwjOJO4rN3mdfNhYRAvo@fsH4wpzSgU14xLfE@v2I4ILqyd1ShL3tPGrnsmYrCaV/xtjRTt6YxzDC5MSBlSwZSzyinAfPj7RpyBQMaBZ8m6n5zq6BVcNrlAu0/bhoJOMtY2HUa@aC9SNC3IRw2oxalFsds0pre)

## C, 85 bytes

```c
#define C(a,b,c)if(a*a+b*b==c*c)return 1;
f(a,b,c){C(a,b,c)C(b,c,a)C(c,a,b)return 0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcxNCoMwEIbhvacYLIUknYKxlRbEldfoJommZGEoYlfi2dMPqav@BDKBvA/jjnfnUtp1vQ@xp1YYtuxk8MIoc7DKNo1TTo799Bwj6TrzbzFvtBWYbPBist1oUS8pxIkGE6KQ2ZwRzmPElxf5vrvFnMmLiunEdJay/t4Rq39dl1hwwa3opyk1@hWLPgU6raIAKWD0ipb0Ag)

Comment: Outputs `1` for parameters of `1, 1, 1` which is wrong...

Comment: @Neil It's fixed now.

Comment: Question was updated to use ints, might save some bytes.

Comment: `f(a,b,c){a=!((a*=a)+(b*=b)-(c*=c)&&a-b+c&&a-b-c);}`

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY7BCoMwDIbvPkUQBolWsDrZQPImu7TZOjysiLiT89m7zOvmQkIg38dPpLqLpBTQGW@Eluk2P6eIrmBHJfqCPTGjFCz0csy@lG1V0q9piDM83BCRsiUDrXHSU8D8cL3E3EBAa@DTRP1v3hloDRx3ucLuH7eNBpx0Oth1Gv2gPWvQt6EcNqNWpVbHbtKa3g "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
SU&0)s=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzhUzUCz2Pb//2hDIx0FY3MgNo0FAA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `[12, 37, 35]`.

```
S     % Implicit input. Sort
      % [12, 35, 37]
U     % Square each entry
      % [144, 1225, 1369]
&0)   % Push last entry and remaining entries
      % STACK: 1369, [144, 1225]
s     % Sum of array
      % STACK: 1369, 1369
=     % Isequal? Implicit display
      % STACK: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## J, 10 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog*

```
=`+/@\:~*:
```

### original answer

```
(+/@}:={:)@/:~*:
```

`/:` sort the squares `*:`, then check if the sum of the first two `+/@}:` equals the last `{:`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/zW09R1qrWyrrTQd9K3qtKz@a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkK6QpGCuYKJgqgICfk55CZWoxQsIUKIVFwtBIwdhcwdgUQ8LIUMHYAmwYSCIvHyFuoGBsYKFgaAqX@Q8A)

Comment: that's awfully damn clever

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
m²ø½*Ux²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bbL4vSpVeLI&input=WzEyLDM3LDM1XQ)

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x¡`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ë²Ñ¶Ux²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXih&code=y7LRtlV4sg&input=WzEyLDM3LDM1XQ)

Comment: I like the square symbols in your solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 16 bytes

```julia
!x=x⋅x∈2x.*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fscK24lF3a8Wjjg6jCj2tiv9p@UUKFQqZeQoa0aY6CsY6CiaxOgrRQNoUyjQ0AgqbA7EpiGdkCGRZAGUhHAMgzwDINTSN1eTidCgoyswrSdNQUtU1NClW0LVTUC2OyVPSUajQUVCs0ORKzUv5DwA)

#### How it works

Let **x = [a, b, c]**.

`x⋅x` is the dot product of **x** and itself, so it yields **a² + b² + c²**.

`2x.*x` is the element-wise product of **2x** and **x**, so it yields **[2a², 2b², 2c²]**.

Finally, `∈` tests if the integer **a² + b² + c²** belongs to the vector **[2a², 2b², 2c²]**, which is true iff
**a² + b² + c² = 2a²** or **a² + b² + c² = 2b²** or **a² + b² + c² = 2c²**, which itself is true iff
**b² + c² = a²** or **a² + c² = b²** or **a² + b² = c²**.

Answer (score 4):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity),  <s>49</s>  31 bytes

```
...)...
..IEO..
.M)2s^.
}Re+=..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTxOIufT0PF39QbSvplFxnB5XbVCqtq2e3v//0YZGOgrG5kBsGgsA)

#### Explanation

Every Triangularity program must have a triangular padding (excuse the pun). That is, the **i**th line counting from the bottom of the program must be padded with **i - 1** dots (`.`) on each side. In order to keep the dot-triangles symmetrical and aesthetically pleasant, each line must consist of **2L - 1** characters, where **L** is the number of lines in the program. Removing the characters that make up for the necessary padding, here is how the code works:

```
)IEOM)2s^}Re+=     Full program. Input: STDIN, Output: STDOUT, either 1 or 0.
)                  Pushes a zero onto the stack.
 IE                Evaluates the input at that index.
   O               Sorts the ToS (Top of the Stack).
    M)2s^}         Runs the block )2s^ on a separate stack, thus squaring each.
          R        Reverse.
           e       Dump the contents separately onto the stack.
            +      Add the top two items.
             =     Check if their sum is equal to the other entry on the stack (c^2).
```

Checking if a triangle is right-angled in Triangularity...

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 68 bytes

```java
a->{java.util.Arrays.sort(a);return a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1]==a[2]*a[2];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY7BasMwDIbveQodnS01cbqyQUihD7Beegw5qKk7nLlysJ2OEvLsmVK2eyuQEJK@X3@HV1y5XlN3@p5biyHAJxoaDUXtz9hq2I9H56xGglbwtG4A03IKEaNpYQ8EFcy42o4dK8khGit33uMtyOB8FHzrdRw8AdZ587KUV6zV0qmmqrAulrZoymkuk344Whb90746c4ILmxGH6A193T@PCXAcbiHqi3RDlD2voiVBshWkf@BucVxn8JbBZkrT8mFgw8zjgCoyWL9zPvGkUHz/8ZSvQuXM5Aypf2pKpvkX)

Comment: Can you save some bytes using currying rather than an array?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Nope, because `sort` takes an array.

Comment: Suggest `Math.hypot(a[0],a[1])==a[2]` instead of `a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1]==a[2]*a[2]`

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b,$c=$args|sort;$a*$a+$b*$b-eq$c*$c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyVRRyVJRyXZViWxKL24pji/qMRaJVFLJVFbJUlLJUk3tVAlWUsl@f///0aG/40t/psCAA)

Sorts the input, stores that into `$a,$b,$c` variables. Then uses Pythagorean theorem to check whether `a*a + b*b = c*c`. Output is either Boolean `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
n{R`+Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/rzooQTvw//9oQx0gjAUA)

Comment: The first example fails to detect [1,1,1] is not a valid input (common issue on some other attempts), but the second works fine.

Comment: @NickLoughlin Oops, removed first example

Comment: You could do `n{RÆ_` to save a byte.

Comment: @Emigna The `_` could also be a `>`, since in this case they have the same effect - making a truthy output if the top of stack is `0` and falsy otherwise. Since `1` is the only truthy value in 05AB1E, `>` will increment `0` to `1` and output it; for other values, it will increment it and output it. Since any value other than `1` is falsy, it will be a falsy output.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 34 +2 (-ap) bytes

```
$x+=($_*=$_)/2for@F;$_=grep/$x/,@F
```

seems that can be shortened to 29 +2 but there is a warning: smartmatch is experimental

```
$x+=($_*=$_)/2for@F;$_=$x~~@F
```

the question i couldn't prove but it works in all tests i've tried is if the number (a^2+b^2+c^2)/2  can be a substring of a number (a^2/2 b^2/2 or c^2/2) which would give a false positive.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lQttWQyVey1YlXlPfKC2/yMHNWiXeNr0otUBfpUJfx8Ht/39jBVMFk3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UTCwA)

Comment: This can cut down to 35 + 2 by eliminating the `@F` assignment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXstWJV5HpUIbSOkbpeUXObhZq8TbphelFuirVOjrOLj9/2@sYKpg8i@/oCQzP6/4v25iAQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali, thanks, and even 34 +2, editing

Comment: We don't count `-ap` as +2 bytes, but, instead, Perl 5 with the `-ap` flags is not the same language as Perl 5 without any flags.

Comment: thanks Erik seems the rules have changed since i've posted, don't hesitate to update

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
²DS)Σε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9Aml2DNc4vPbf3/P9rQSEfB2ByITWMB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```
(λ(a b c)(=(+(* a a)(* b b)(* c c))(*(expt(max a b c)2)2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw7DsIwEET7nGIkmlloiDsKDrM2GxQRLGQZkbtxh1zJbEgbTfE0mk/R9LDaDpPmO8rfdLzZMGbD8M5oXL5URCThlSceoVBxRMQVyQMnbX5VPnXG1g0ukSYdP2WsNmVwfQtnhAtCL3tBj@Cj9gM)

#### How it works

Tests if `a^2 + b^2 + c^2` is equal to twice the largest of `a^2`, `b^2`, and `c^2`.

Returns `#t` for right triangles and `#f` for all other inputs.

---

- *-4 bytes thanks to @xnor's suggestion to use `expt`.*

Comment: Awesome ;) but i think `(define fun` must be a part of the code...

Comment: Thank you! I think it's conventional to say that pure functions are allowed as answers. The `(define fun ...)` on TIO is just for convenience: we could equally well use this function as `(... 3 4 5)` where `...` is the function. (So we could have a header of `(print (` and a footer of `3 4 5))` if you prefer.)

Comment: (But this is one of my first Racket submissions, so I'm not too clear on what Racket-specific conventions there are, if any. Some past solutions using Racket have included `#lang racket` in the code; some haven't.)

Comment: Racket is so wordy that it's shorter to repeat `(max a b c)` than to do a `let` binding, huh? I don't suppose it would be shorter to bind as an argument to a `λ`? Or, isn't there an exponentiation built-in?

Comment: I tried some variants along those lines and none were shorter; I didn't try this one, but it looks like `((λ(x)(* x x 2))(max a b c))` doesn't beat `(*(max a b c)(max a b c)2)` either. There *is* an exponentiation built-in, but `(expt x 2)` is worse than `(* x x)`.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Then how about `(*(expt(max a b c)2)2)`?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
s¦ΣḥuĖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9nYWlh//9zwqbOo@G4pXXElv9l4oaR/1sxMiAzNyAzNV0)

- `s¦` - **s**quare each.
- `Σ` - sum.
- `ḥ` - **ḥ**alve.
- `u` - sq**u**are root.
- `Ė` - contains? Check if the square root is in the input.

Comment: Is it better than sorting version?

Comment: @mdahmoune I believe it is better. I will try to solve it the other way around, but TBH I think that'd be longer.

Comment: Upvote any way :)

Answer (score 3):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 10 bytes

```
§²2^r]‘\+e
```

### Explained

```
§²2^r]‘\+e
§           # Sort the input list
 ²2^r       # Square each element in the list.
     ]      # Duplicate it on the reg stack.
      ‘     # Pop the top (largest) element off it
       \+   # Swap it, sum the rest of the list.
         e  # Are they equal?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6r2FopGBsrmBsqvn/0PJDm4ziimIfNcyI0U79/x8A)

Comment: Why duplicate the list?

Comment: @mdahmoune RProgN2 doesn't keep the original list on the stack when popping an element off it, but stacks are by reference, so to keep the stack to do the sum part of it, it needs to be duplicated first.

Comment: Thanx upvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>29</s> 24 bytes

```
f(v)=v~==2*vecmax(v)^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P02jTNO2TKusztbWSKssNTk3sQIoEmf0v6AoM69EI00j2ljHRMc0VlOTCy5iqgMUwxAxBor8BwA)

Saved five bytes by an obvious change from `norml2(v)` to `v*v~`.

Inspired by other answers.

Here `v` must be a row vector <s>or a column vector</s> with three coordinates.

Example of use: `f([3,4,5])`

Of course, you get rational side lengths for free, for example `f([29/6, 10/3, 7/2])`.

If I do not count the `f(v)=` part, that is 19 bytes. The first part can also be written `v->` (total 22 bytes).

**Explanation:** If the three coordinates of `v` are `x`, `y` and `z`, then the product of `v` and its transpose `v~` gives a scalar `x^2+y^2+^z^2`, and we need to check if that is equal to twice the square of the maximum of the coordinates `x`, `y`, `z`.

**Extra:** The same `f` tests for a [Pythagorean quadruple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple) if your input vector has four coordinates, and so on.

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: @mdahmoune You can use [this `tio.run` link](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P02jTNM2L78oN8cIxLI10ipLTc5NrABy4oy4Cooy80o00jSijXVMdExjNTURIqY6QDEMEWOgyP//AA). However, it is much nicer to just install [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) locally.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
max(Ans=R►Pr(min(Ans),median(Ans
```

Now works for inputs in any order and is shorter as well. Another -1 thanks to @MishaLavrov

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: This only detects sorted right triangles: input of `A=5`, `B=4`, `C=3` would not be correctly handled.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for pointing that out, it's actually shorter handling as a list. Now it works for inputs in any order.

Comment: If we leave off a single `)`, then `max(Ans=R►Pr(min(Ans),median(Ans` is also valid (though the computation we're doing here is different) and is one byte shorter.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That's interesting, I see what you mean. I think the expressions are equivalent for all non-negative inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 31 bytes

```
->a{a,b,c=*a.sort;a*a+b*b==c*c}
```

Takes input as a list of 3 integers. Uses some ideas from other solutions.

Comment: I just realized the answer I just posted is almost identical to yours. I promise I didn't copy yours (I actually had it sitting for a while in the "Post an answer" box), but since yours was submitted first, if you think mine is too close, I'll delete it.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard It's pretty much the same thing. this was a funny coincidence lol. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 9

```
q~$W%~mh=
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E%24W%25%7Emh%3D&input=%5B3%205%204%5D)

**Explanation:**

```
q~      read and evaluate the input (given as an array)
$W%     sort and reverse the array
~       dump the array on the stack
mh      get the hypotenuse of a right triangle with the given 2 short sides
=       compare with the longer side
```

Comment: Some explanations ;) ?

Comment: @mdahmoune here you go

Comment: Dang it.  Didn't you write that language? Doesn't seem fair. (joke)

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 64 bytes

```
(apply(lambda(x y z)(=(+(* x x)(* y y))(* z z)))(sort(read)#'<))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck7DoAgEEXRrUxi4Rst1U4XM34KEtQJUDBsHrE6N7mHd1ErNLgnVYiqN3i591OQyagwNowYKFPmhpHxb2mnRXxDQrjk5K5fmStXLDTTxB8)

As usual in Common Lisp, true is `T` and false is `NIL`.

Answer (score 3):

## MS Excel, 48 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from the range [A1:C1] and outputs to the calling cell.

```
=Let(a,A1^2,b,B1^2,c,C1^2,Or(a+b=c,b+c=a,a+c=b))
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript 6, recursive way, 40 Bytes

```
f=(a,b,c)=>c<a|c<b?f(b,c,a):a*a+b*b==c*c
```

```js
f=(a,b,c)=>c<a|c<b?f(b,c,a):a*a+b*b==c*c
console.log(f(4,5,3));
console.log(f(4,5,6));
```

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 42 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c){c=c<a|c<b?f(b,c,a):a*a+b*b==c*c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU3tCsIwDHyVULC0M0LXWhy64rOk0WlhDlHBH368em2FkZA77sIdr07MOQ@KMCLrFwfu6c193A@qCEh6Sw0tYxND4IZ3n3yhNM3fz3Maj@p7Z5oGJRaHOgIloYwoWevrLU2PvwMC5w5dQhyswUPZSsrxFVoLbgOu6LYF14E3lRlwpgPrzQ8)

Comment: That's a nice approach!

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 47 bytes

Returns `FALSE` for right-angled Triangles, else `TRUE`:

```
=ISERR(FIND(SQRT((A1^2+B1^2+C1^2)/2),A1&B1&C1))
```

Comment: Now that is clever

Comment: Is there proof why it work?

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 31 bytes

```
k=>(sum(j*j for j:k)/2)**.5in k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z/b1k6juDRXI0srSyEtv0ghyypbU99IU0tLzzQzTyH7f0FRZl6JRppGtLGOgomOgmmspuZ/AA)

Credit to user202729 for the idea [go upvote them](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146061/68942)

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 6 bytes

```
ᛦDᚺS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9uZWlt///hm6ZE8J2QrOGaulPwnZWa//9bMTIgMzcgMzVd)

Comment: Could you plz add some explanations?

Comment: @mdahmoune You can activate [debug mode](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9uZWlt///hm6ZE8J2QrOGaulPwnZWa//9bMTIgMzcgMzVd/m9wdGlvbnP/LWQ) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/74163)

```apl
{(+/2÷⍨⍵*2)∊⍵*2}
```

[Try it!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%28+/2%F7%u2368%u2375*2%29%u220A%u2375*2%7D3%204%205&run)

Outputs 1 for true, 0 for false.

Thanks to @Adám for 1 byte.

#### How it works

```apl
{(+/2÷⍨⍵*2)∊⍵*2}          # Anonymous function
 (     ⍵*2)               # Each input (⍵) to the 2nd power
    2÷⍨                   # divided by 2
  +/                      # Sum
           ∊              # "is in"
            ⍵*2           # Each input (⍵) to the 2nd power
```

This uses the same logic as @user202729's Jelly answer, so some credit goes to them.

Comment: You should probably update the code on the top, it still has those parens around `⍵*2`

Comment: `(⍵*2)÷2` can be golfed to `2÷⍨⍵*2`.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3, 81 bytes

```
func r(v:[Int]){let a=v.sorted{$0<$1};print("\(a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1]==a[2]*a[2])")}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 61 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/ax=%1*%1,y=%2*%2,z=%3*%3,!((x+y-z)*(y+z-x)*(z+x-y))
```

Outputs `1` or `0` appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
K_m*ddSQqstKhK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zs@VyslJTiwsLjEO8P7//9oQyMdBWNzIDaNBQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 70 bytes

```
proc R {a b c} {expr $a[set H ==hypot(]$b,$c)||$b$H$a,$c)||$c$H$a,$b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc6xDoIwFEbhvU/xD3cQ40C5NLKwMzC5Eoa2IXHA0EBNNKXPXqu4fWc73s4puXWxuCFoGNiIML3cCtLDNnl0aNv72y3@NJK5kC32nQx1pP@2h00R0/zQDj2CCAqMOkIEhvoiq87in2QFvoJVFKGS4AaHSnDZQObIB@7pNwx56RypH2P6AA)

Still too long.

Comment: You think it can be more golfed?

Comment: Failed outgolf: [`proc R L {expr hypot([lindex [set L [lsort $L]] 0],[lindex $L 1])==[lindex $L 2]}`](https://tio.run/##Tc2xCsIwGATgPU9xQwcFh6R/g136Bpm6hgxSAwrRhiaFSsizx1QR3L7j4C5OrhS/zBNGKCS7@QW3l5/jQbv782o36GBjrbQL8xLRKGPAzenXNgrCHIfhL7cmF/e4@H2PJQlCl8ESQe6o6qroI9GCziCZWWoFqMdXHMR7iBoykl9jgB7351ze)

Comment: Another fail: [`proc R L {expr hypot([[set I lindex] [set L [lsort $L]] 0],[$I $L 1])==[$I $L 2]}`](https://tio.run/##Lc2xCsMgFIXhPU9xhgwtdIjeSLPkAQJOWcWhpEILtpFoIEV8dmvSbt@/nBMmm7Nb5gkjJKLZ3ILHx83hpJQ3AQPs8303m8aREsr6eQmopdZo9EXVQzGYPvf931ynbF83t@9VUYDQJlSRIHYUtUV0iHHQFSRSFTkDdfipATUdWImE6Nbgocb9MeUv)

Comment: Thanx for the additional less golfed solutions, could you add them to the answer plz?

Comment: I already tried to understand some solutions posted on other answers, and it happens, I will add more golfy solutions to main answer using the same approach. I will not publish the fails on the main answer as they are more recent and less golfy; and are also clickable links on the comments to working online demos.

Answer (score 2):

## [Eukleides](http://www.eukleides.org), 81 bytes

```
x=number("")^2;y=number("")^2;z=number("")^2
print x==y+z or y==x+z or z==y+x?1|0
```

I thought Eukleides would handle this nicely using geometric builtins, but this actually turned out to be longer than just testing against the Pythagorean theorem, because the right triangle assertion is picky about order, and we have to turn our sides into a triangle first:

```
d e f triangle number(""),number(""),number("")
print right(d,e,f)or right(e,f,d)or right(f,d,e)?1|0
```

...which is 100 bytes. One nice thing about that one is it'll error out given an impossible triangle. Anyway, for either one, input is via STDIN, output is 1 for right, 0 for non-right via STDOUT. Doing a function was actually longer in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
}/sK^R2Q2K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1a/2DsuyCjQyPv//2hDIx0FY3MgNo0FAA)

My first Pyth submission! Explanation:

```
     R        right map
    ^ 2       squaring
       Q      of the input
   K          save this in K
  s           sum up
 /      2     divide by 2
}        K    test if this sum is in K
```

saved a byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: 10 bytes: `}/sK^R2Q2K` or `/K^R2Q/sK2` (the former returns `True/False`, the latter returns `1/0`)

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 156 bytes

```
bool f(int*a){int g=[](int*b){return b[0]>b[1]?b[0]>b[2]?0:2:b[1]>b[2]?1:2;}(a);int c[2]={g?0:1,g>1?1:2};return pow(a[c[0]],2)+pow(a[c[1]],2)==pow(a[g],2);}
```

Comment: Since this doesn't work without the `#include<math.h>`, you need to include it in the bytecount. Note that instead of using `pow`, you can just [multiply each element with itself](https://tio.run/##LY9NDoMgEIX3nIKkG2ltIrbdgD8HISwQLSFBNIorwtkpWGfz5r2ZfJOR6/pUUsY4LIuB30JbdxfIJ4GqZfz0A/Lb5I7NwoFVvBsY5v3V1byvSE1y9HeY1DQUAtFMkClpvUoruFQdzsNAL5RgMiH4/dJHVnz5pG0rmMpOcRriTVtpjnFq9LK7bRJzBzJ/FtoWCHgAU@XAsHTvU8JXCd@BnvHuRkLkcjjYNOk/gygI8Qc) to avoid the `#include`.

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: [135 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY7BDoMgEETvfgWNF7E0qba9gOiHEA6IlJAgGsWT4dst0D3M5k0mOyvX9aGlvK5yUl/jFLDVCOuxH1nDh7xbPjxxi5Pxpwa3hXEefKuotYBnAk1tJSCSMUDPm0a6b1IwkE35Y3NAsFryOutdMBmPJcqbUsF0Is1JuErjpD0m1Zll95sSc5/LZmFcBYuzAHGSYVks@iDwQuAdSLZ3P2Esl8ODrovfWUiKcP0A "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 109 bytes

```
#lang racket/base
(define (isright a b c)
  (if (equal? (+ (* a a) (* b b)) (* c c))
      "yes"
      "no"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUw5DoMwEOx5xcg0u6SgIKl5y9pZwAI5ig1FXm9sJDLNnJoobtU953aTMCNerreStKG3Tj4oyKfo52WHwMJxg5JMIP0eso2gB6grlXBlC8uXcGVZpxXmp8ncOnwMc/5/PjHgxfkE)

Comment: It seems not working for 5 3 4?

Comment: So this answer is not valid for the challenge. Also if you don't do trivial golfs such as [those ones](https://tio.run/##PYsxDoAgEAS/csHmTgsLtfYtB55IJBgBC1@PaGE12clOZLNLLo3nYCF@o9ecpOAiqwuCLkVntwwMGgyhW1HOi/2MHbZVMlVo0PTS1AepW5JS4VBE5a9HGGCi8gA) just because you're lazy then you are not a _serious contender_ to the challenge.

Comment: @user202729 While valid to point out, that may not be the most helpful way to address a new user.

Comment: @sdfbhg The "trivial golfs" being pointed out are that (1) by convention we say that a pure function (`λ` expression) is a valid solution, leaving the `# lang` and `define` to the header and (2) an easy way to make the code shorter is to delete spaces around parentheses. Also, you can return `#t` and `#f` rather than `"yes"` and `"no"`, bringing us [here](https://tio.run/##TYtBDkAwEEX3TvETmxmWdO0s0yoaIlF1OndwpaFiYfXy/suP4maftFxkHRFfKaj3Q1g9wh7DOCWl6ySBhWPy2yFLRzVVEAg/sLCc6Z7MrFzQd0OLBubnJi@sNw).

Comment: The point of both of these is so that different Racket submissions can be on an equal footing: if one person decides to write `#lang racket` and leave in spaces while another does not, we can't easily compare the actually *different* optimizations they found. (Anyway, as has been also mentioned, your submission needs to be fixed to work for right triangles not listed in a-b-c order.)

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 12 bytes

```
(+/2÷⍨×⍨)∊×⍨
```

Uses the same method as [this Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146061/55550).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtExQ0FDS09Y0Ob3/Uu@LwdCCh@aijC8xQ0FQwVjBRMP3/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 13 bytes

```
22ω^÷Σ2ω^=Σ←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638/9/I6Hxn3OHt5xaDaNtziz/MnbLzUduE////RxvrmOiYxgIA)

This helped me realize ... I screwed up the NOT function (and the boolean conversion function).

### How it works (cross-compatible function)

```
22ω^÷Σ2ω^=Σ←
2             = push 2 to the stack
 2ω^          = push ω^2 to the stack (functions vectorize)
    ÷         = pop a, then b. push a/b (rational) to the stack
     Σ        = sum
      2ω^=    = equality test with ω^2
          Σ  = boolean conversion
            ← = output
```

Comment: You can ask Dennis to pull it yourself [here](https://gitter.im/tryitonline) or by contacting him at `feedback@tryitonline.net`

Comment: Is it possible to avoid computing ω^2 twice?

Comment: Maybe somehow, but MY doesn't have a duplicate command yet.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam 10

```
q~$_.*~-+!
```

Simplest one I found but also shortest

```
q reads input as string. Leave input formatted as array [3 4 5]
~ dumps it to stack 
$ sorts array
_ duplicates array
.* multiplies each element by itself
~ dumps array to stack
-+ determines largest minus two smallest numbers
! if 0 return 1 and 0 if anything else
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOJV5Pq05XW/H//2hjBRMFs1gA)

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: @mdahmoune sure. done.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>96</s> 94 bytes

```go
package r;import"sort";func I(i...int)bool{sort.Ints(i);return i[0]*i[0]+i[1]*i[1]==i[2]*i[2]}
```

Test:

```go
import "r"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(r.I(3, 5, 4))
    fmt.Println(r.I(12, 37, 35))
    fmt.Println(r.I(21, 38, 5))
    fmt.Println(r.I(210, 308, 15))
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCoMwDIbvPkXw1G5SbJ1sID6At93FgxOVMG2l1pP47F062M0F8vOHL/kzGr@03bsde5hb1FGE82Ksg3iYXex/w0oaF8OmO6gYghACteMvY6Y9IFFptzLkhe3dZjVgnTaXIFesZXCyKUusVbCqOfw3KLxjHPYIqOibeFoKnTSrWJZAnsCN8xMmVQLZnTo/xUoSetD9H5oSTonLsHD4Dw)

Comment: Is it possible to do it without sorting?

Comment: I tried to do some stuff with complex numbers, but they were all higher character count. `import "math/cmplx";cmplx.Abs()`

Comment: You can drop the space between `import` and `"sort"`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>31</s> 23 bytes

```
map(.*.)|.[[add/2]]!=[]
```

Expects input in form of 3 element array, e.g. `[5, 3, 4]`

Expanded

```
  map(.*.)           # square each element
| .[[ add/2 ]]!=[]   # true if index of sum/2 element exists
```

Thanks to [mdahmoune](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71398/mdahmoune) for suggesting shorter approach then my original one.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8H22qo2Cso2ASq6MAAsq6unYKlanFXNFAQVNs4oZGQA3mQGwKkkKIGxkCxSyAmsA6wOJ5@SBhA6C4AVDC0DQWLlzzPzexQENPS0@zRi86OjElRd8oNlbRNjr2//9/@QUlmfl5xf91dfNKc3J0M/MKSkuAnKLEct380hIgBwA)

---

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 31 bytes

```
sort|map(.*.)|(.[:2]|add)==.[2]
```

Expects input in form of 3 element array, e.g. `[5, 3, 4]`

Expanded

```
  sort                   # put elements in order
| map(.*.)               # square each element
| (.[:2]|add) == .[2]    # is sum of first two equal to third?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBCsIwEAXQvacIuGklE5poUIR6kZBFoC4qNYlNQink7MZJF7pxYBb/ff7jVZSk5EjJSVNSbw9wI@s97BSi/Odc4OCML2v1c8HRLjjaFptbV7lD77DgUn85l@DmmJ/GN@zA2twwdRU6m2Fo@54poUt5Ox9HZ0MBsGmaYLQ@RQyzWcCliOED)

Comment: The problem is equivalent to whether `(a² + b² + c²) ÷ 2` is in `{a², b², c²}`, do you think this approach will be shorter on Jq?

Comment: Indeed that's a better approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you plz add also the first solution too :)

Comment: Done!  See also [original edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/146168/1)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

```apl
(+/∊×∘2)×⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wQNbf1HHV2Hpz/qmGGkCaR6VwDFFUx1FIx1FEy40kCUKYRlaAQUNAdiUyDHyBDIsADKGYA5BkCeAZBrZGoAAA)

`×⍨` square (lit. multiplication selfie)

`(`…`)` apply the following anonymous tacit function on that:

`+/` the sum

`∊` is a member of

`×∘2` the doubled amounts

Answer (score 2):

Two answers found by refining the [answer by Steadybox](/a/146077) and incorporating the technique in the [Java answer by Kevin Cruijssen](/a/146064):

## C, 52 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c){return(a*=a)+(b*=b)==(c*=c)|b+c==a|c+a==b;}
```

## C, 74 bytes

```c
#define _(a,b,c)a*a+b*b==c*c||
f(a,b,c){return _(a,b,c)_(b,c,a)_(c,a,b)0;}
```

## Test program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int test(int a, int b, int c, int expected)
{
    int actual = f(a,b,c);
    if (expected != actual) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d %d %d => %d\n ", a,b,c, actual);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return test(5, 3, 4, 1)
        +  test(3, 5, 4, 1)
        +  test(12, 37, 35, 1)
        +  test(21, 38, 50, 0)
        +  test(210, 308, 250, 0)
        ;
}
```

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: I've provided a `main()` - anyone *can* try the code!  It's all standard C...

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
GK2ek+=#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/d2yg1W9tW@f///8Y6CqY6CiYA)

Managed to cut off two bytes by changing the approach, here's how it works now:

```
          \ Implicit Input                  eg. [3, 4, 5]
G         \ Sort the stack descendingly         [5, 4, 3]
 K2e      \ Square all items                    [25, 16, 9]
    k+    \ Sum last two                        [25, 25]
      =   \ Check equality (1 or 0)             [1]
       #  \ Output result                       PRINT: 1
```

### Original Version, 10 bytes

```
gK2eSk2/=#

           \ Input implicitly on stack.              eg. [5, 4, 3]
 g         \ Sort the stack ascendingly.                 [3, 4, 5]
 K2e       \ Square all items.                           [9, 16, 25]
 Sk2/      \ Append stack sum divided by 2               [9, 16, 25, 25]
 =#        \ Print equality of last two items (1/0)      PRINT: 1
```

Comment: Could you plz add the first solution too?

Comment: @mdahmoune done.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 4, 68 bytes

```
func f(v:inout[Int]){v.sort();print(v[0]*v[0]+v[1]*v[1]==v[2]*v[2])}
```

Accepts a mutable array as inout argument and prints `true` or `false`.

[Swift Sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ef1b08ffe2623101cecf76).

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 29 bytes

```matlab
sum(a=input("").^2)==max(2*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/uDRXI9E2M6@gtERDSUlTL85I09Y2N7FCw0grUfP//2gTBVMF41gA)

Input has to be given in a format octave understands as a vector, like `[3 5 4]` or `[12;35;37]`.

Checks for Pythagoras's theorem: first, square all the sides, then check if the sum of squares of all the sides is twice the square of the hypotenuse.

Output will be either `ans = 1` or `ans = 0`

Comment: Could you add some explanations?

Comment: Sure. There you go.

Answer (score 2):

### C# (53)

The shortest possible code I could find was the one that looks like the JAVA solution:

```
(a,b,c)=>{return(a*=a)+(b*=b)==(c*=c)|a+c==b|b+c==a;}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jY1BS8MwGIbP5ld8DA9Jl0rXrSjU9CJ4UhA8eBg7JDErgS6BJB2Mrr@9ZupsT5sfJCEvz/O90qfSOjW0Xpsa3g8@qF2JZMO9hzdna8d3qEMQxwcetIS91Z/wyrXBPrjorDfAXe3JN/NDnua5NfJRm0BhvIS1TQVbYIBuBsypoJKwqnMqtM5gnjBO5lgkTBDGsEyYJEc@l4yJozg9vOyHEv01PFnjbaPuPpwO6kUbhW9nBYUlhRWkaQXdFhd0SVekn5HyohWVYmL9fq97izzW3cdTnNUxuW7ni8g9xK7sbI/Jf@wswlmk8@mCSTju6FE/fAE)

### Array-input (58)

```
a=>{Array.Sort(a);return a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1]==a[2]*a[2];};
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), <s>25</s> 18 bytes

```
D,f,?,caaBcB*#s/2=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HXic5MdEp2UlLuVjfyPb///9Ghgb/jQ0s/huZGgAA)

-7 bytes thanks to [mdahmoune](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71398/mdahmoune)

<sub>Yes, I got outgolfed in my own language by 7 bytes. So what?</sub>

### How does it work?

```
D,f,?,      - Create a variadic function, f. Example arguments: [5 3 4]
      c     - Clear the stack;      STACK = []
      a     - Push the arguments;   STACK = [[5 3 4]]
      a     - Push the arguments;   STACK = [[5 3 4] [5 3 4]]
      Bc    - Push the columns;     STACK = [[5 5] [3 3] [4 4]]
      B*    - Product of each;      STACK = [25 9 16]
      #     - Sort the stack;       STACK = [9 16 25]
      s     - Push the sum;         STACK = [9 16 25 50]
      /     - Divide;               STACK = [9 16 2]
      2     - Push 2;               STACK = [9 16 2 2]
      =     - Equal;                STACK = [9 16 1]
```

Implicitly return the top element on the stack

### Old version

```
D,f,?,c2 2 2B]a@BcB`#s/2=
```

The only difference is the squaring of each element (`aaBcB*` in the golfed version, `` 2 2 2B]a@BcB` `` in this version), so I'll quickly explain how this part works

```
              - Stack is currently empty
2 2 2         - Push 2 three times;             STACK = [2 2 2]
     B]       - Wrap the stack in an array;     STACK = [[2 2 2]]
       a      - Push the arguments as an array; STACK = [[2 2 2] [5 3 4]]
        @     - Reverse the stack;              STACK = [[5 3 4] [2 2 2]]
         Bc   - Push the columns of the stack;  STACK = [[5 2] [3 2] [4 2]]
           B` - Reduce each by exponentiation;  STACK = [25 9 16]
```

Comment: Why not push the input twice and reduce by multiplication?

Comment: @mdahmoune because I over complicate things. Golfing now

Comment: Upvote ;) please can you put the first solution too, it’s interesting

Comment: @mdahmoune added!

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

This is depressingly long.

```
{$2f#)\:+=}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/WsUoTVkzxkrbtvZ/3f9oQyMFY3MFY9NYAA)

Anonymous block that takes input as an array of integers on the stack and returns `1` (truthy) or `0` (falsey).

Explanation:

```
{      e# Stack:        [12 37 35] 
 $     e# Sort:         [12 35 37]
 2f#   e# Square each:  [144 1225 1369]
 )     e# Pop:          [144 1225] 1369
 \     e# Swap:         1369 [144 1225]
 :+    e# Sum:          1369 1369
 =     e# Equal:        1
}      e# Result: 1 (truthy)
```

#### Old solution

```
{2f#_:+2/#)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/2ihNOd5K20hfWbP2f93/aEMjBWNzBWPTWAA)

Anonymous block that takes an array of integers on the stack and returns a truthy or falsy integer.

Comment: I like the swap trick ;)

Comment: Is it possible to add a link to test the solution please?

Comment: @mdahmoune TIO links added, thanks.

Comment: @Challenger5 what are the rules for including code in the header/footer like that?  If I accept the input as array (realize I can do now) and include "q~" in the header like you did my answer is only 8.

Comment: @kaine The way CJam works is that `{}` defines an anonymous function that accepts input from the stack. `q~` reads input and places it on the stack, and the `~` at the end runs the block. I don't have to score that part because anonymous functions are allowed by default, so I put it in the header/footer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That means i can make mine 10 by using those rules. The brackets, however are required.

Comment: @kaine Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 18 bytes

```
[sorted:*rev...+=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcdBCoMwEAXQ/ZziuzIqhphpUARL7iEupMZNqZEYe/3U4u69I86vt1tSGg8folv6MrivlLIapmT7lUgIA8ajIAiGudFocAs2f@sG3MGo2wqsOuirBUYCchvcHlDXT9g1z@DPSBO2z7ynHw)

### Explanation

This is an anonymous function that takes an array of three integers. It sorts  (`sorted`), squares each element of the array (`:*`), and reverses the array with `rev`. This will give an array with the largest value in the front. `...` pushes each individual member of the array onto the stack, which would make the stack look like:

```
c^2  b^2  a^2
```

`+` addes the top two members, yielding:

```
c^2  (b^2+a^2)
```

`=` tests for equality. yielding the expression `a^2 + b^2 == c^2`, which is only true for right triangles.

Comment: Like the :* part ;)

Answer (score 2):

### GNUOctave, 32 bytes

```
A=input("")
sum(A.^2)/2==max(A)^2
```

The input must be like : `[1,2,3]` so Octave can evaluate it to a Matrix.

`A.^2` squares all the elements of the matrix.

Outputs 1 if the triangle is right-angled, 0 otherwise.

You can try it online : https://octave-online.net

**Edit (27 bytes):** I saw [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146204/25100) answer I thought I could find a better solution. I took the idea of squaring the matrix at the beginning. I don't feel like this deserves upvotes since it wasn't really my whole idea to begin with.

```
A=input("").^2
sum(A)/max(A)
```

Outputs 2 if the triangle is right-angled and anything else if it isn't.

Comment: The newline counts as a byte too, better to replace it with ";", which also eliminates the spurious output (so the edited version is actually 28 bytes). The rules do require a specific output for both true and false cases; I don't think "anything else than 2" qualifies as specific.

Answer (score 2):

## Axiom, 39 bytes

```
f x==(y:=sort x;y.1^2+y.2^2=y.3^2=>1;0)
```

f(x) function
Input one list of at last 3 numbers

Output 1 (it is right triangle)

Output 0 (it is not right triangle)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>12</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
²ĐƩ₂⇹∈
```

Explanation:

```
                 implicit input (as a list, i.e., "[A,B,C]")
 ²               square each element in the list
  Đ              duplicate the list (on stack twice)
   Ʃ             sum elements in list on top of stack
    ₂            divide sum by 2
     ⇹           swap top two items on stack
      ∈          check if sum/2 is in the list of squares
                 implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//0KYjE46tfNTU9Kh956OOjv//o411THTMYgE)

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: Back when I posted this answer, it wasn't on TIO

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
~${.*}/-+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v06lWk@rVl9XW/H//2hTBWMFk1gA)

Takes an array as input and outputs 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
~$           # Sort the array                  [3 4 5]       [1 2 3]
  {.*}/      # Square all elements             9 16 25       1 4 9
       -     # Subtract the last two numbers   9 -9          1 -5
        +    # Add the numbers left            0             -4
         !   # Negate the answer               1             0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
#.#==2Max@#^2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1lP2dbWyDexwkE5zkjtf0BRZl5JtLKuXVq0cmysmoK@g0J1tamOgrGOgkmtjkI1kDaFMg2NgMLmQGwK4hkZAlkWQFkDCM8AyDUA8o2AArX/AQ)

Thanks to @att for –4 bytes!

Checks if the sum of the squared numbers is equal to twice the square of the maximum number.

Comment: `Tr[#^2]`->`#.#`

Comment: @att I must have been asleep at the wheel when I wrote this code. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 140 bytes

```
Fun<Ap<Fun<bor<Eq<Add<A<1>,A<2>>,A<3>>,bor<Eq<Add<A<2>,A<3>>,A<1>>,Eq<Add<A<3>,A<1>>,A<2>>>>>,Mul<A<1>,A<1>>,Mul<A<2>,A<2>>,Mul<A<3>,A<3>>>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nNLchJLEkt/u9YYPPfrTTPBkiDqKT8IhvXQhvHlBQbRxtDOx1HGyM7EGkMJFHkjGCiIGV2OnBxY5gIWCcQ6PiW5sDMMoRzjWBGQ7jGUNPs7P7rcHF62hib24FpQyMIbWxqx2X3HwA)

Anonymous function (all TCH functions are anonymous) that takes 3 integers as inputs.

Cool language that uses C++ templates evaluated by a typedef. Interestingly, this is a similar length to the [actual C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146127/66421).

---

```
Fun<  //Anonymous function declaration
  Ap< //Apply following function with arguments (a²,b²,c²)
    Fun<
      bor<
        Eq<Add<A<1>,A<2>>,A<3>>,  // (a²+b²=c²)|
        bor<                      //((b²+c²=a²)|
          Eq<Add<A<2>,A<3>>,A<1>>,// (c²+a²=b²))
          Eq<Add<A<3>,A<1>>,A<2>>
        >
      >
    >,
    Mul<A<1>,A<1>>,Mul<A<2>,A<2>>,Mul<A<3>,A<3>> //arguments (a²,b²,c²)
  >
>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 35 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.375 bytes

```
²:∑½c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiwrI64oiRwr1jIiwiIiwiMTIsIDM3LCAzNSJd)

Ports Thunno 2

### Explained (old)

```
s²Ṙḣ∑=
s²     # sort and square the input
  Ṙ    # reverse the list so that it's in descending order
   ḣ   # push the head of that, and the rest of that to the stack
    ∑= # does the sum of the list equal the other item?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 39 24 bytes

With 15 bytes saved thanks to Jenny_mathy.

```
#^2+#2^2==#3^2&@@Sort@#&
```

---

`Sort` ensures that the diagonal will be the third element of `z`.
`z[[1]]^2` means

**Example**

```
#^2+#2^2==#3^2&@@Sort@#&[{3,5,4}]

 (*True*)
```

Comment: Can it be done as a function?

Comment: It is a pure function, employed as if it were a single word.

Comment: 3 bytes shorter `#&@@(z=Sort@#)^2+z[[2]]^2==z[[3]]^2&`

Comment: 24 bytes:  `#^2+#2^2==#3^2&@@Sort@#&`

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 66 bytes

```
function f(...)t={...}table.sort(t)print(t[1]^2+t[2]^2==t[3]^2)end
```

This could be simplified by using table call syntax which would mean that the table does not need to be constructed in the function, saving 9 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/NQmB/1)

[Try it online on tio.run!](https://tio.run/##XYvBCsIwEETv@Yo9NtiGNDXopV9SFGJNsBDS0mwOIn57HMSTh@XNm2VicbWGkmZe1kShUUpJHl/Am90tepXXnRuW274kcOovV3PgyQDjyNMASp/uteuI98KPJ7HPTLPLPovQ2JaGlo4SEbS/2BvUJ5yVQmAZXMx/Q9PjfcZEy69pqIYbFPUD)

Comment: PLZ could you add the two solutions?

Comment: Can be golfed with `function f(...)t={...}`

Comment: Are those not [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYvBCsIwEETv@Yo9NtiGNDXopV9SFGJNsBDS0mwOIn57HMSTh@XNm2VicbWGkmZe1kShUUpJHl/Am90tepXXnRuW274kcOovV3PgyQDjyNMASp/uteuI98KPJ7HPTLPLPovQ2JaGlo4SEbS/2BvUJ5yVQmAZXMx/Q9PjfcZEy69pqIYbFPUD)?

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>48</strike> 47 bytes

```php
sort($a);echo($a[2]**2==$a[1]**2+$a[0]**2)?1:0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSaBttrGOqYxJr/b84v6hEQyVR0zo1OSMfyIg2itXSMrK1BbIMQSxtIMMAxNC0N7QysP7/HwA)

Outputs 1 for true, 0 for false.

Comment: If it is acceptable to emit empty string for false, you can shave the four character ternary.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 49 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range [A1:C1] and output to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
[2:2]=[(1:1)^2]:?[Or(A2+B2=C2,B2+C2=A2,A2+C2=B2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) - <s>23</s> 22 Bytes, <s>22</s> 21 if falsy value doesn't need to be the same every time

```
!-+^@KSQZ2^@K1 2^@K2 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1FXO87BOzgwyghIGSqASCMFo///jXVMdEwB)

Returns `True` or `False`

or (if falsy value does not need to be the same every time)

```
-+^@KSQZ2^@K1 2^@K2 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1c7zsE7ODDKCEgZKoBIIwWj//@NdUx0TAE)

Returns `0` or a number other than `0`

This can probably be golfed a lot

Explanation:

```
!        Logical negate; Makes 0 true and others false. Not necessary if falsy values can be different 
 -       Subtract
  +      Add
   ^     To the power of
    @    Index in
     K   Assign variable K, returning K
      S  Sorted
       Q Input
     Z   Zero
    2    2
   ^     To the power of
    @    Index in
     K   Variable K
     1   1
    2    2
   ^     To the power of
    @    Index In
     K   Variable K
     2   2
    2    2
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL NARS 14 chars

```
{⍵∊⍨√2÷⍨+/⍵*2}
```

(seen in some other answer) test:

```
  f←{⍵∊⍨√2÷⍨+/⍵*2}
  f 3 4 5
1
  f 1 1 1
0
  f 5 3 4
1
  f 3 5 4
1
  f 12 37 35
1
  f 21 38 50
0
  f 210 308 250
0
```

Here ⍵ is the argument of function f.

```
{⍵∊⍨√2÷⍨+/⍵*2}   
           ⍵*2} if ⍵=1 2 3, ⍵*2 will be 1 4 9 (square the argument ⍵)
         +/     if ⍵*2 is 1 4 9 here sum it 1+4+9=14(sum list)
     √2÷⍨       here makes d=sqrt( (sum list above)/2 )
 ⍵∊⍨            here return 1 if d is element of ⍵, else return 0
                 because ⍨ reverse arguments of its left operator ∊
```

This follow from this: Given a, b, c the length of one triangle, they are the length of one right triangle <=> a^2+b^2=c^2 and a,b,c different from 0.

```
  |\
  | \
  |  \ 
 a|   \c
  |    \
  |_____\
     b
  a^2+b^2=c^2 <=> (a^2+b^2+c^2)/2=(2*a^2+2*b^2)/2=a^2+b^2=c^2 <=> 
  <=> (a^2+b^2+c^2)/2 ∊ {a^2, b^2, c^2}
```

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: @mdahmoune the code would run only in a Nars interpreter... I don't know where find that interpreter in the net...( Because I use one symbol function sqrt,  not present in other Apl interpreters) So no trust in what I say... (for see if run ok one would have download Apl Nars, load the code , execute it)

Comment: So could u plz explain your solution?

Comment: @mdahmoune done... I possibly make wrong something...

Comment: @mdahmoune because I make one error in understand the code, so I change the explanation where I make that error (sqrt( sum/2))

Comment: This is 28 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
à‚nOË
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8IJHDbPy/A93//8fbWiko2BsDsSmsQA)

Comment: some explanations plz :)?

Comment: `nàsOQ` is another. Not thinking it's possible below 5.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 14 bytes

```julia
L->L'L∈2L.^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@1@iYPvfR9fOR93nUUeHkY9enNH/3MQCDaBQQVFmXklOnkaJho@mpo6CRrSpjrGOSaxOtLGOgqmOAohlaKSjYGwOxKZAjpEhkGEBlDNQAPMMgFwDIN/I1CBWU/M/AA)

Based @mdahmoune's hint that "The problem is equivalent to whether (a² + b² + c²) ÷ 2 is in {a², b², c²}" - this expresses the condition "(a² + b² + c²) is in {2a², 2b², 2c²}" for a given array `L=[a,b,c]`.

`L'L` is multiplying the array by itself as a matrix multiplication, so

```julia
[a b c]*[a    = a^2 + b^2 + c^2
         b
         c]
```

`L.^2` is elementwise squaring, so is equal to `[a^2 b^2 c^2]`.

`∈` is a synonym to `in`, and checks membership - so the code checks that "sum of squares evaluates to twice of any one of the squares".

Just saw @Dennis' previous [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146161/8774) and saved a few bytes thanks to that. This golf improves on it by two bytes, by using `L'L` instead of `L⋅L` (⋅ is a 3-byte Unicode character).

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

```php
echo($a**2+$b**2+$c**2)/2==max($a,$b,$c)**2;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZJRS8MwEMff@ynOElgyA3adU7HWvfns@ywljdEWujY0qQzEz14vWdieBoMGchz3v/vdHYmu9fSy1bWGiFhlrIEcdhHgWUH@Glx3Fk2nR7sAH11zuOewKfhZVgetJOoo22FURyUkXKBsODjQTIobBEEzKasUGY945y6VrhDyhDMlF0A315MSRCXISufDji/2cBWmyKKvflBC1jT8CWHAe@zX57SNsZQITipOJMMf48VdaIjlLqmvSmPFYCnLJiXrHguWy/SWVN5KtOwuzfO9OJxRGMwmV0yEtKNoEY2Yb2VL2SrRIcqjf8RQfo57TUNaCLsuQGnV9y07AU7DhXULBluI34UxH10MzxC/iaZFN4v@pn8)

Half the sum of the squares of the sides should equal the square of the max side.  Emits `"1"` for true and `""` (empty string) for false.

The TIO link runs all the tests in a loop.

Comment: Let me know if taking the inputs as three independently pre-set variables abuses the `The input and output can be given in any convenient format.` rule.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>[a*=a,b*=b,c*=c].includes((a+b+c)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZJBT8MgFMfv/RTPXgYd1q46NVvQmwcPauKx6YExtmBI2xRqNGafvb7CGj1osmwkvMDj//89yONNvAsrW92486peq94oB05ZZ4FDEQGOLx@HMdFV07nJAopLBlcM5iX7OVMfjZLDoWs7FfI79i9gzmBgHA8YyiPjeMAsR/sNzhNekc/Qf4s3yf5knB0IyZCSISY/iRN6cn0AoVxGm7oFMvYadBV6Tvdgz8QP8Pj6/JQ2orWK@KV1ra62evNJvLwYYpl6NaVLbw0l0ftbEZJBIKTrhEEBiXoi2IpJyu8KkXBcJxy3CZcDU5purSwhYrqaSnqR0358FiVpui8akLKubG1UauotGfF8vMk9xC/C2hgWED8IbWIa7fpv)

Half the sum of the squares of the sides should equal the square of the max side.  Returns a bool.

The TIO link runs all the tests in a loop.

Comment: Making a shorthand function seemed shorter than a console.log().

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```rust
|n|{n.sort();n[0]*n[0]+n[1]*n[1]==n[2]*n[2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZnZNaopBmlZanoZZbWhJdamYSq6lrl5Sfn2P7vyavpjpPrzi/qERD0zov2iBWC0Ro50UbgliGsba2edFGIKZRbO1/a67E4uLUohJFjTSIUcY6pjpAwzQREopwGTOoTO1/AA)
Takes in an `&mut[u64]` of at least three elements and proceeds to sort and test if the Pythagorean theorem holds. If sorting floats in rust were easier (it's hard because they can't implement the `Ord` trait, which is required by the sorting functions) I could use the `hypot` function and wind up with this:

```rust
|n|{n.sort();n[0].hypot(n[1])==n[2]}
```

which is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 55 bytes

```
DEF R(T)SORT T
RETURN SQR(T[0]*T[0]+T[1]*T[1])==T[2]END
```

Comment: If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!

Comment: I don't think one exists, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you PLZ tell us how can test your code?

Comment: A quick search found this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petit_Computer . I don't know if you can download it and run it on DSi emulator though.

Comment: It appears it defines a function R with argument T and assumes T to be a zero indexed array containing 3 numbers. SQR must be square root function. Unlike other BASICs this one uses C-like == rather than = for comparison. I guess I would just have to find a copy of the manual online to assess it as the code is really straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 90 bytes

```lua
t={...}for k,v in pairs(t)do t[k]=tonumber(v)end table.sort(t)print(t[1]^2+t[2]^2==t[3]^2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAr@xRKYS0jr5ECpQMJNPYti7R2zdPc5l8e2ayr1Lq2yrC3j@QCpw@4SVIrhXI7bOlWu4jRBSPjGUF8iFHdVWkdk5MpemGedEdOd2wlpxpSmYe2fD0Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
øUx²z q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CO0IpDm6oUCv//jzbVUTDWUTCJBQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
²DS½Ƈ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKw5tcgk-tPdY-5LipORiqOCC5aY6CsY6CiYQLgA)

Port of [DELETE_ME's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146061/114446).

##### Explanation

```python
²DS½Ƈ  # Implicit input         ->  [5, 3, 4]
²      # Square each value      ->  [25, 9, 16]
 DS    # Duplicate and sum      ->  [25, 9, 16]  50
   ½   # Halve the sum          ->  [25, 9, 16]  25
    Ƈ  # Check for containment  ->  1
       # Implicit output
```